# Custom Master Page with Top Navigation and Left Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have successfully converted an HTML Page to a SharePoint 2013 Master Page. I also created a Custom Page Layout. Using both them I have created my SharePoint Site with 30+ pages. Each page is consisted with the Top Header Navigation as it is inheriting from the Master Page I have used. Now I need the left navigation inherit from the master page also. It gives me the advantage of updating it from the master page and affects it through the entire SharePoint Site.

But at the moment I am inserting the Left Nav using a web part as an HTMl code snippet individually for each and every page. If needs a modification I have to go through all the pages and do the modification. This is not convenient also. I want to this left nav like the SharePoint Current Navigation alternative but within my Page Layout.

Is there an option to chat within these forums?

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks and regards,

Chiranthaka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think  you  are trying to do:

http://info.scdot.org/StructuralDesign/SitePages/BridgeDrawingsDetails.aspx

This is a sharepoint page with an HTML header, footer, and left accordion nav.  I am not using a separate "Page Layout" as SP terms it.  It is in SP 2010.

I added a DIV in the master page to house the left accordion navigation, and positioned it with CSS.

HTML  Snippet:

```
<div id="AccordionContainer">
            <div id="Accordion1" class="Accordion">
<h3 class="accordionShow"><a>CADD Design</a></h3>
<div class="insideAccordionPanelContent">
    <!-- First link is for site Map Only and should not appear in Accordion -->
    <a href="http://www.scdot.org/doing/cadd.aspx" class="siteMapShow panelTitle">CADD Design</a>
    <!-- Accordion Links -->
    <p><a href="http://www.scdot.org/doing/cadd_DesignFiles.aspx">CADD Design Files</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.scdot.org/doing/cadd_SUE.aspx">Subsurface Utility Engineering (SUE)</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.scdot.org/doing/cadd_RoadwayDesign.aspx">Roadway Design Files</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.scdot.org/doing/cadd_BridgeDesign.aspx">Bridge Design Files</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://www.scdot.org/doing/cadd_Traffic.aspx">Traffic Engineering Files</a></p>
</div>
<h3 class="accordionShow"><a>Engineering Directives</a></h3>
<div class="insideAccordionPanelContent">
    <!-- First link is for site Map Only and should not appear in Accordion -->
    <a href="http://info.scdot.org/Construction_D/sitepages/Engineering_directives.aspx" class="siteMapShow panelTitle">Engineering Directives</a>
    <!-- Accordion Links -->
    <p><a href="http://info.scdot.org/Construction_D/sitepages/Engineering_directives.aspx">Engineering Directives</a></p>
    <p><a href="http://info.scdot.org/Construction_D/ED/ED-index.pdf">Engineering Directives Index (PDF)</a></p>
</div>
<h3 class="accordionShow"><a>Hydraulic Engineering</a></h3>
```

Perhaps if you examine my page with developer tools (F12) or Firebug it will help.  Hope  that helps!

D

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. But you are advising me to add this to the Master Page template is it?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Yes, You can add your Div with your navigation in the master page, and position it with your style sheet.  This works in 2013 and 2010.  The HTML snippet is a sample of the code that's in MY div, you, of course, will enter your own navigation links.

Comment: Can't we do anything using Visual Studio 2013 like editing the web.config file of the SharePoint Site.

Comment: Certainly, that's an option, but one beyond my expertise.  And, I think HTML and CSS will do what you need.